# How to convert new text data to a predefined dfm?

Tags: quanteda

I am doing topic modeling with the package topicmodels. So I new to split the data into train set and test set. I wonder is it possible to transform the test data into a predefined dfm object (generated by the training data).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only in topic modeling but also in other out-of-sample prediction, you can use `dfm_select()` with a DFM as a pattern to make features of DMF for training and test set identical.

```
require(quanteda)
require(topicmodels)

corp_train <- data_corpus_irishbudget2010[1:7]
mt_train <- dfm(corp_train)
lda <- LDA(convert(mt_train, "topicmodels"),  10)

corp_test <- data_corpus_irishbudget2010[8:14]
mt_test <- dfm(corp_test)
mt_test <- dfm_select(mt_test, mt_train) # make the features identical

post <- posterior(lda, mt_test)
apply(post$topic, 1, which.max)
```